# Simple initilizators in method parameters

Tags: c#, fluent, object-initializer

I built a fluent interface like this:

```
criador.Include("Idade", 21).Include("Idade", 21);
```

Can I do something like this:

```
criador.Include({"Idade", 21},{"Idade", 21});
```

I tryed to user method with params keyword:

```
public myType Include(params[] KeyValuePair<string,object> objs){
    //Some code
}
```

But I need to do this:

```
criador.Include(new KeyValuePair<string, object>{"Idade", 21}, new KeyValuePair<string, object>{"Idade", 21});
```

The point is that i dont want to write no "new" keyword on the methods

Comment: Try out criador.Include( { {"Idade", 21},{"Idade", 21} });

Comment: Why don't you want to use new?  It's a powerful tool in your toolbox.

Comment: Your code using KVP doesn't compile: you have to use parens, not braces.

Comment: you seem to have the same keys for your key/value pairs. Do you mean to do something like .include({"one":1, "two":2}) like you would do in a language like python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an implicit conversion:

```
public class ConvertibleKeyValuePair
{
    public ConvertibleKeyValuePair(string key, int value)
    {
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator ConvertibleKeyValuePair(string s)
    {
        string[] parts = s.Split(';');
        if (parts.Length != 2) {
            throw new ArgumentException("ConvertibleKeyValuePair can only convert string of the form \"key;value\".");
        }
        int value;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out value)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("ConvertibleKeyValuePair can only convert string of the form \"key;value\" where value represents an int.");
        }
        return new ConvertibleKeyValuePair(parts[0], value);
    }

    private string _key;
    public string Key { get { return _key; } }

    private int _value;
    public int Value { get { return _value; } }

}
```

// Tests

```
private static ConvertibleKeyValuePair[] IncludeTest(
    params ConvertibleKeyValuePair[] items)
{
    return items;
}

private static void TestImplicitConversion()
{
    foreach (var item in IncludeTest("adam;1", "eva;2")) {
        Console.WriteLine("key = {0}, value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked your suggestion :P

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `Tuple`s:

```
criador.Include(Tuple.Create("Idade", 21), Tuple.Create("Idade", 21));
```

Or you could create a type that can hold the values:

```
criador.Include(new StrIntDict{ {"Idade", 21}, {"Idade", 21} });
```

Where `StrIntDict` is basically `Dictionary<string, int>`: it has to implement `IEnumerable` and have a method `Add(string, int)`. (You could use `Dictionary<string, int>` directly, but I think your goal is brevity, which such a long name doesn't help much.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write several overloads: one overload for each additional couple of parameters required.
It may seems an overkill but actually can make code quite clear.

```
public void Include(string k0, object v0) { ... }
public void Include(string k0, object v0, string k1, object v1) { ... }
public void Include(string k0, object v0, string k1, object v1, string k2, object v2) { ... }
public void Include(string k0, object v0, string k1, object v1, string k2, object v2, string k3, object v3) { ... }
public void Include(string k0, object v0, string k1, object v1, string k2, object v2, string k3, object v3, string k4, object v4) { ... }
```

Each method does a different operation.
The bad thing, you have a fixed number of maximum numbers of parameters.

Good thing, you can optimize the call for each function increasing performance.

You can also use this technique using extensions methods for a base class or an interface if needed.